Sort all tables in a Word doc which has "XYZ" in first row
I already have to script which sorts the table 3 column A in Word using the order specified in a Excel file sheet 2 and it is doing a great work for me but this script sorts only the table 3 but I want to sort all tables in the doc which has "xyz" in first row. The sorting in Word tables starts from row 3.
Could someone review and adjust the script based on the condition I specified? Only modification I need is to sort all tables which has "xyz" in first row.
"xyz" will be used to detect the tables we want to sort.
Sub SortTableColumnAUsingExcelOrder()

    Dim wdDoc As Document
    Dim wdTable As Table
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim excelWorkbook As Object
    Dim excelSheet As Object
    Dim sortOrder() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim tempRow As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowText As String
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim newRow As Row
    Dim colCount As Long
    Dim fileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim filePath As String

    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

    Set fileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fileDialog
        .Title = "Select the Excel File"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            filePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No file selected. Exiting.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = False
    Set excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set excelSheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    lastRow = excelSheet.Cells(excelSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row

    ReDim sortOrder(1 To lastRow)
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        sortOrder(i) = excelSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    Set wdTable = wdDoc.Tables(3)
    colCount = wdTable.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        cellValue = sortOrder(i)

        For rowIndex = 3 To wdTable.Rows.Count
            Dim tableCellValue As String
            tableCellValue = wdTable.Cell(rowIndex, 1).Range.Text
            tableCellValue = Left(tableCellValue, Len(tableCellValue) - 2)

            If tableCellValue = cellValue Then
                Set tempRow = wdTable.Rows(rowIndex).Range
                rowText = ""

                For j = 1 To colCount
                    rowText = rowText & wdTable.Cell(rowIndex, j).Range.Text & vbTab
                Next j
                rowText = Left(rowText, Len(rowText) - 1)

                wdTable.Rows(rowIndex).Delete

                Set newRow = wdTable.Rows.Add

                Dim rowData() As String
                rowData = Split(rowText, vbTab)

                For j = 1 To colCount
                    newRow.Cells(j).Range.Text = rowData(j - 1)
                Next j

                If i = 1 Then
                    newRow.Select
                    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
                Else
                    For j = 1 To i - 1
                        newRow.Select
                        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
                    Next j
                End If

                Exit For
            End If
        Next rowIndex
    Next i

    Dim tableCell As Cell
    For Each tableCell In wdTable.Range.Cells
        tableCell.Range.Text = Replace(tableCell.Range.Text, vbCr, "")
    Next tableCell

    excelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    excelApp.Quit
    Set excelApp = Nothing
    Set excelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set excelSheet = Nothing
    Set wdTable = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

    MsgBox "Sorting and cleanup completed!", vbInformation

End Sub


Do you want to write your code in vba or python? So please remove the wrong tag. Have you tried to include a for-each loop over the wdDoc.Tables

Replace Set wdTable = wdDoc.Tables(3) with For Each wdTable in wdDoc.Tables, and add Next wdTable after Next tableCell.

It causes the infinite loop, don't know why, like the table get sorted then get unsorted and it doesn't stop.

This question is similar to: Sorting tables in Word based on order set in Excel sheet 2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I asked the question, but I got a solution for that, the code I attached in this question is working great, but I want to sort all tables which has "Parts Required" in first row. This script currently sorts only table 3 when I tried to do sorting for all it cause the infinite loop like first sorting happens then table get unsorted same process is getting repeated.

@VKK so show your not working code (with the infinite loop) and describe what is not working correctly. You also consider the create a minimal reproducible code.

Little modification was needed I did it, could you please check the last question I posted? I'd highly appreciate if you could provide some help.

@VKK You may consider to post your correct code as an answer.
